# Why variable is not changed after modification?

Tags: typescript

I have Pagination class:

```
export class Pagination {
public localPagination(type: IPaginationLocal): void {
        this.paginationType = type;
        this.fetchData();
    }

 public fetchData() {
    this.paginationType.data = this.paginationType.data.slice(this.from, this.to);    
 }

}
```

**Using:**

```
    this.plans = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    this.pagination.localPagination({
       data: this.plans,
       type: modePagination.LOCAL
    });
   console.log(this.plans);// It must be sliced
```

As you can see I pass variable `this.plans` to class: `this.pagination.localPagination()`:

Then class makes slice input data in method `fetchData()`.

After pagination execution I do:

```
 console.log(this.plans);
```

It should return sliced array, but returnы the initial array `this.plans`.

Comment: Use `splice` instead of `slice`.

Comment: Why? to return modified array instead new?

Comment: To modify the array's reference. This: `this.paginationType.data = this.paginationType.data.slice(this.from, this.to); ` will replace `this.paginationType.data` to point to a new array. What you want to do is modify the array itself, not replacing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You print the initial thing, not the thing you stored:

```
console.log(this.pagination.paginationType.data);
```

`Array.prototype.slice` returns a new array, it does not not modify the original one.

Answer (score 2):

You never change

> this.plans

you are changing the variable

> this.paginationType.data

Comment: `this.paginationType.data` refers to this.plan is not?

Answer (score 1):

You should return the updated value as you are not modifying the actual reference.

```
export class Pagination {
public localPagination(type: IPaginationLocal): any {
        this.paginationType = type;
        this.fetchData();
        return this.paginationType.data;
    }

 public fetchData() {
    this.paginationType.data = this.paginationType.data.slice(this.from, this.to);    
 }

}
```

and use is like following

```
this.plans = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    this.plans = this.pagination.localPagination({
       data: this.plans,
       type: modePagination.LOCAL
    });
   console.log(this.plans);// It must be sliced
```